# Two Matlab icons in Dash

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, unity-dash, matlab

I installed Matlab R2014a on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit without any problems; however the default entry in the `dash` could not be pinned to the `launcher`, so I sought an alternative solution and wrote my own `/usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop` files which has the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Icon=/usr/share/app-install/icons/_usr_share_icons_hicolor_48x48_apps_matlab.png
Name=MATLAB R2014a
Comment=Start MATLAB - The Language of Technical Computing
#Uncomment the following line and comment the line after to
#force matlab to use the 32 bits architecture
#Exec=matlab -arch=glnx86 -desktop
Exec=matlab -desktop
Categories=Development;
#Uncomment the following line if you've got several matlab icons in the launcher
#StartupWMClass=com-mathworks-util-PostVMInit
```

My problem is that when I search for `Matlab` in `dash` I get double entries and I also checked the directory `~/.local/share/applications` to make sure that I did not have a `.desktop` file there also. It turned out that the only `.desktop` file I had was the one I created myself, but the two icons kept being displayed despite my efforts to get rid of them by uncommenting the last line in the `matlab.desktop` file as suggested in [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB). Yet the problem still persists and I have no idea why since on my other laptop which is also running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit I did get exactly one icon in `dash` that can work flawlessly when dragged into the launcher. I am very curious about this problem and would like to hear your suggestions and comments.

[image]

Comment: You *must* have two desktop files in `~/.local/share/applications` and/or `/usr/share/applications`, with a different *filename*, but the same name in the `Name=` line. See this post: http://askubuntu.com/a/516346/72216

Comment: @JacobVlijm Okay thanks for pointing it out I will let you know when I solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested I am posting the solution to the problem. I have run the following command in `/usr/share/applications` and `~/.local/share/applications` to find files containing the entry **Matlab** regardless of the case; I learned that trick from 
[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/finding-all-files-containing-a-text-string-on-linux).

```
grep -Ril "Matlab" /usr/share/applications/
```

The output was:

```
/usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop
```

being the file I generated manually. However, when I ran the command in the other directory

```
grep -Ril "Matlab" ~/.local/share/applications/
```

The output was:

```
/home/ongun/.local/share/applications/com-mathworks-util-postvminit.desktop
/home/ongun/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

After checking the first entry (since it was a `.desktop` file) I found that it was the culprit and deleting it remedied the duplicate icon in `Dash`.

Comment: This worked for me.